# Android Bitmap program

Tags: java, android, xml

i have a 400*800 bitmap. 
i need to make from this a smaller bitmap that will be 400*400. this smaller bitmap will have the first pixels from the first one from 1 to 400. 
after that i need to change that so it will have the pixels from 2 to 401 and so on until i will have pixels from 401 to 800 in the bitmap.
how can i do this?
i am doing like this:

```
bkk=((Bitmap)createBitmap(bk,1,1,400,400));
```

but i get the error:

```
The Method createBitmap(Bitmap,int,int,int,int) is undefined for the type aa.engine
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you're not calling the method properly. Change the call to this:

```
bkk = Bitmap.createBitmap(bk,1,1,400,400);
```

This should work.